# How to stop EJBException's stack trace (in every thrown Exception)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, persistence, jersey

A simple

```
throw new WebApplicationException(400);
```

or any other

```
throw new ...
```

Gets thrown by `javax.ejb.EJBException` with the `Caused by:` being the exception you just threw. When monitoring the log, this is a pain because not every exception prints a stack trace. But EJBException does that. >:(

Please understand - EJBException does not affect the application at all, only that it prints an unwanted stack trace with every thrown exception.

The EJBException javadoc says:

> The EJBException is thrown to report that the invoked business method
>   or callback method could not be completed because of an unexpected
>   error (e.g. the instance failed to open a database connection).

There must be a way to keep EJBException quiet...

(Update) Example:

```
@Stateless
@Path("roads")
public class RoadsREST {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "rd")

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<NationalRoads> retrieve() {

        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        Root subs = cq.from(NationalRoads.class);

        List<NationalRoads> roads = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();

        if (roads.isEmpty()) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(404);
        }

        return roads;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why? If you keep EJBException quit you won't see anything in the log. It's not the exception itself that prints to the log file, it's the surrounding call stack.

Comment: So your saying that the calling method that encounters the thrown Exception is throwing EBJException to report that thrown Exception?

Comment: Yep, but it may depend on your EJB version. Maybe you can post some example code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to create a subclass of `WebApplicationException` and annotate it with `@ApplicationException`, like so:

```
@ApplicationException
public class RESTException extends WebApplicationException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public RESTException(Status status, String msg) {
        super(Response.status(status).entity(msg).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build());
    }
}
```

this should stop the Exceptions from appearing in your logfiles as well

Comment: This prevents the exception from getting wrapped to EJBException, which is why it would stop the exceptions from appearing in log files ([api](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ApplicationException.html)). It may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can set log level by editing logging.properties in your domain's config directory or with asadmin set-log-levels. There is also a screen for that in admin gui, but using that sometimes breaks logging completely